# Passing Function names as parameter to define a generic function

Tags: python, function, class

I have the following Python codes (some functions defined in the same class), as you can see. The 2 functions are basically the same, except they are calling different functions: one is calling `self._init_module`; and another is calling `self._config_module`. So what I would like to do is to define a common generic function which can pass a function name as the parameter. How should I implement this?

```
# ULONG LAURAKIT_API LauraKitInitModule_1B(LAURA_HANDLE modHandle, ULONG *regAddr, ULONG *regData, UCHAR *size)
self._init_module = _lib.LauraKitInitModule_1B

# ULONG LAURAKIT_API LauraKitConfigRegister_1B
#                           (LAURA_HANDLE modHandle, OPERATION *ope, ULONG *regAddr, ULONG *regData, INT *size)
self._config_module = _lib.LauraKitConfigRegister_1B

def init_module(self, mod_h):
    """


    :param mod_h: module handler
    :return: operation, reg_addr, reg_data, size.value
    """
    mod_handle = ct.c_ulong(mod_h)

    Reg_Addr_Arr = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN
    Reg_Data_Arr = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN
    Reg_Oper_Seq = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN

    operation = Reg_Oper_Seq()
    reg_addr = Reg_Addr_Arr()
    reg_data = Reg_Data_Arr()

    size = ct.c_int(0)

    self._ok = self._init_module(mod_handle, operation, reg_addr, reg_data, ct.byref(size))

    return operation, reg_addr, reg_data, size.value

def config_module(self, mod_h):
    """
    Exactly the same function implementation as the init_module

    :param mod_h: module handler
    :return: operation, reg_addr, reg_data, size.value
    """
    mod_handle = ct.c_ulong(mod_h)

    Reg_Addr_Arr = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN
    Reg_Data_Arr = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN
    Reg_Oper_Seq = ct.c_ulong * MAX_ARR_LEN

    operation = Reg_Oper_Seq()
    reg_addr = Reg_Addr_Arr()
    reg_data = Reg_Data_Arr()

    size = ct.c_int(0)

    self._ok = self._config_module(mod_handle, operation, reg_addr, reg_data, ct.byref(size))

    return operation, reg_addr, reg_data, size.value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just pass the function directly, like:

```
def process_module(self, mod_h, process_func):
    # Pre-processing...
    self._ok = process_func(mod_handle, operation, reg_addr, reg_data, ct.byref(size))
    return operation, reg_addr, reg_data, size.value

def init_module(self, mod_h):
    self.process_module(mod_h, self._init_module)

def config_module(self, mod_h):
    self.process_module(mod_h, self._config_module)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def generic_caller(self, function_name, *args):
  if hasattr(self, function_name):
    function = getattr(self, function_name)
    function(*args)
  else:
    pass # Some error handling here
```

for `o.generic_caller('func', 1, 2, 3)` it will do exactly what would `o.func(1, 2, 3)`

### Example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def generic_caller(self, function_name, *args):
...     if hasattr(self, function_name):
...       function = getattr(self, function_name)
...       function(*args)
...     else:
...       print ("There is no atribute called: " + function_name)
...   def dog(self):
...     print "hau"
...   def cat(self, times):
...     for _ in xrange(0, times):
...       print "mew"
... 
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.generic_caller('dog')
hau
>>> bar.generic_caller('cat', 3)
mew
mew
mew
```

Comment: can you give a actual implementation?

Comment: what is the type of the `function_name`?

Comment: `string`, You cas say it from example where i put function name in quotes

Comment: I know it must be s `string` type. I adopted your method to implement the code, but it got error.